# Jackson JSON Deserialisation with Abstract Class

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization

i am trying following example:

```
class Zoo  
{  
  public Collection<Animal> animals;  
}  

@JsonTypeInfo(
use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog"),
@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat"),
})
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="Animal",namespace=WSSupport.NAMESPACE)
@XmlType(name="Animal",namespace=WSSupport.NAMESPACE)
@XmlSeeAlso({
  Dog.class,
  Cat.class
})
public abstract class Animal {

}

@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="Cat",namespace=WSSupport.NAMESPACE)
@XmlType(name="Cat",namespace=WSSupport.NAMESPACE)
@JsonTypeName("cat")
public class Cat extends Animal {
    String miauType;
}

@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="Dog",namespace=WSSupport.NAMESPACE)
@XmlType(name="Dog",namespace=WSSupport.NAMESPACE)
@JsonTypeName("dog")
public class Dog extends Animal {
    String barkType;
}
```

With following JSON i get the ERROR:

```
{ "animals": [ { "type": "dog", "barkType": "BAAARK" }, { "type": "cat", "miauType": "MIIIIAU" } ] }
```

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of at.dataphone.logis3.rest.Animal, problem: abstract types
>   can only be instantiated with additional type information at Source:
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@5b65311; line: 1,
>   column: 13

I am using jackson 2.4.1
Is this possible at all?